# Findbugs warning: Equals method should not assume anything about the type of its argument

Tags: java, equals, findbugs

When running FindBugs on my project, I got a few instances of the error described above.

Namely, my overriding versions of equals cast the RHS object into the same type as the object in which the overriding version is defined.

However, I'm not sure whether a better design is possible, since AFAIK Java does not allow variance in method parameters, so it is not possible to define any other type for the equals parameter.

Am I doing something very wrong, or is FindBugs too eager?

A different way to phrase this question is: what is the correct behavior if the object passed to equals is not the same type as an LHS: Is this a false, or should there be an exception?

For example:

```
public boolean equals(Object rhs)
{
    MyType rhsMyType = (MyType)rhs; // Should throw exception
    if(this.field1().equals(rhsMyType.field1())... // Or whatever
}
```

Comment: that sounds a bit strange. please show us some code.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Typically, when implementing equals you can check to see whether the class of the argument is equal (or compatible) to the implementing class before casting it.  Something like this:

```
if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
    return false;
MyObj myObj = (MyObj) obj;
```

Doing it this way will prevent the FindBugs warning.

A side note to address a comment:
Some people argue to use `instanceof` instead of `getClass` to check type safety.  There is a big debate on that, which I was trying not to get into when I noted that you can check for class equality **or** compatibility, but I guess I can't escape it.  It boils down to this - if you use `instanceof` you can support equality between instances of a class and instances of its subclass, but you risk breaking the symmetric contract of `equals`.  Generally I would recommend not to use `instanceof` unless you know you need it and you know what you are doing.  For more information see:

- http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=4744
- [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)
- http://www.macchiato.com/columns/Durable5.html
- http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html (Apache common's implementation helper)
- http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t92613.rhtml (Eclipse's default equals generator)
- NetBeans generator also uses getClass()

Comment: Essentially what this means is: rather than throwing a ClassCastException, your equals() method should return false.

Comment: But is that the correct practice in those situations? I mean, ideally I would have liked a compile-time type check, which I can't get because of Java limitations.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with checking for equality between unrelated types? It's a question with a perfectly fine and well-defined answer.

Comment: Sometimes it makes sense to check unrelated types, but usually it's unnecessary.  When you do, you have to be very careful to make sure the equivalence relation is symmetric and transitive.

Comment: Sorry - -1 for the getClass() compare, which should be instanceof to allow subclasses to override and call super.equals(oth) and then proceed with subclass object specific checks.

Comment: Damn too late to take back my downvote!  While I still don't agree (yet), I *do* agree that the instanceof vs. same class is not cut and dried.  Will look at this further - thanks for the links.

Comment: While this code addresses the original FindBugs issue, it seems to result in FindBugs now flagging the code with NP_EQUALS_SHOULD_HANDLE_NULL_ARGUMENT. So you likely need to add in a null check like:
`if ( obj2 == null || getClass() != obj2.getClass() )`

Answer (score 7):

You're probably doing something like this:

```
public class Foo {
  // some code

  public void equals(Object o) {
    Foo other = (Foo) o;
    // the real equals code
  }
}
```

In this example you are assuming something about the argument of equals(): You are assuming it's of type Foo. This needs not be the case! You can also get a String (in which case you should almost definitely return false).

So your code should look like this:

```
public void equals(Object o) {
  if (!(o instanceof Foo)) {
    return false;
  }
  Foo other = (Foo) o;
  // the real equals code
}
```

(or use the more stringent `getClass() != o.getClass()` mentioned by Dave L.

You could also look at it this way:

```
Integer i = new Integer(42);
String s = "fourtytwo";
boolean b = i.equals(s);
```

Is there any reason that this code should throw a `ClassCastException` instead of finishing normally and setting `b` to `false`?

Throwing a `ClassCastException` as a response to `.equals()` wouldn't be sensible. Because even if it is a stupid question ("Of course a String is never equal to a Foo!") it's still a valid one with a perfectly fine answer ("no" == `false`).

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to ignore said findbugs warning. In practice, if equals is called with an object of an unexpected class, it is almost certainly a bug, and you want to fail fast on bugs.

For example, if you have an 'ArrayList files' and call files.contains("MyFile.txt"), it would be nice if you got a ClassCastException. Instead, Java just returns false, and it likely takes a long time until you discover that bug.

Answer (score 0):

I start my equals(Object) implementations like this:

```
if ((object == null) || !(object instaceof ThisClass)) {
    return false;
}
```

This will also prevent the FindBugs warning but will not automatically return `false` when a subclass of ThisClass is being handed in. It might also be considered equal, especially if its `equals(Object)` method hasn’t been overridden.

Comment: The null check is redundant with instanceof. Be careful using instanceof; if the refined contract of a non-final equals doesn't spell out the conditions for equality (like java.util.Set does), you're likely to break the symmetry requirement.